# Issue with the checkstyle,findbugs and pmd plugins for SonarQube5.3 version

Tags: plugins, sonarqube, sonarqube5.3

I am getting the below mentioned error when the following plugins are included:

- sonar-checkstyle-plugin-2.4.jar
- sonar-findbugs-plugin-3.3.jar
- sonar-pmd-plugin-2.5.jar

Logs:

```
ERROR : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to instantiate class
  [org.sonar.plugins.checkstyle.CheckstylePlugin] of plugin [checkstyle]
  at org.sonar.core.platform.PluginLoader.instantiatePluginClasses(PluginLoader.java:146) ~[sonar-core-5.3.jar:na]
  at org.sonar.core.platform.PluginLoader.load(PluginLoader.java:73) ~[sonar-core-5.3.jar:na]
  at org.sonar.server.plugins.ServerPluginRepository.loadInstances(ServerPluginRepository.java:274) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
  at org.sonar.server.plugins.ServerPluginRepository.start(ServerPluginRepository.java:108) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
```

The same error is given for the above mentioned plugins.

As these versions are supported for the version 5.3 (with reference to compatibility matrix in official documentation), need some help regarding fixing this error.
I am using MySQL database for the SonarQube 5.3. The installation works fine when the above mentioned plugins are removed from `SONAR_HOME/extensions/plugins` directory.

Is there some issue with this plugins for version 5.3? Has anyone tested these plugins on this version? Let me know if anyone has faced same issues and found out the solution to this problem.

Comment: I have those plugins and start server without any errors. Please add list with all installed plugins.

Comment: I have these plugins installed 
sonar-checkstyle-plugin-2.4.jar
sonar-clover-plugin-3.1.jar
sonar-cobertura-plugin-1.6.3.jar
sonar-csharp-plugin-4.4.jar
sonar-findbugs-plugin-3.3.jar
sonar-fortify-plugin-2.0.jar
sonar-groovy-plugin-1.3.1.jar
sonar-java-plugin-3.9.jar
sonar-motion-chart-plugin-1.7.jar
sonar-pmd-plugin-2.5.jar
sonar-resharper-plugin-2.0.jar
sonar-stylecop-plugin-1.1.jar
sonar-visual-studio-plugin-1.2.jar

The error is given for the 3 plugins mentioned in the first comment

Comment: Please edit question instead of add a lot of information in comments ;).

Comment: Yes. I will do it but please can you provide the possible solution for this problem. This is turning out to be a major blocker.

Comment: I use the same plugins without any errors. I only found that you use deprecated [Fortify Plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Fortify+Plugin) - try to uninstall it. You can also remove all plugins and install one by one. Maybe it will solve the problem.